# Not getting Json object (having a collection) correctly in controller using ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am sending a json object to controller via ajax call, data property of ajax call showing correct data. On post to controller's method -received parameter having collection  and its count is showing perfectly but the properties inside the collection is not showing values.

Here is the code -

Controller-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImageOperations(ImageProcessingModel imageProcessingModel)
{
  return Json("sucess");
}
```

Model-

```
public class ImageProcessingModel
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    private List<ThumbnailImageSubTaskModel> _thumbnailImageSubTaskModel;
    public List<ThumbnailImageSubTaskModel> ThumbnailImageSubTaskModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (_thumbnailImageSubTaskModel == null)
            {
                _thumbnailImageSubTaskModel = new List<ThumbnailImageSubTaskModel>();
            }
            return _thumbnailImageSubTaskModel;
        }

    }
}
```

js-

```
var ImageProcessingModel =
{
    "Source": "test",
    "ThumbnailImageSubTaskModel":allThumbnails.allItems()
}
```

allThumnails.allItems is ko.observableArray() which having values.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ImageProcessingTask/ImageOperations',
    type: 'Post',
    data: ImageProcessingModel,
    success: function (data, status) {
        processEscapeKeyPress = true;
        var fn = window[successCallback];
        fn(data, passDataToCallback);
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        alert(err);
        processEscapeKeyPress = true;
        processAjaxError(xhr, desc, err);
    },
  });
```

here ImageProcessingModel having all values and source is simple a string so this value is coming in the controller only the ThumbnailImageSubTaskModel showing counts but not its value.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A common problem encoutered with sending JSON through AJAX to MVC. Many forget to set the type of data in their AJAX request.

Try setting the datatype and contentType:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ImageProcessingTask/ImageOperations',
    type: 'Post',
    **contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: 'json',**
    data: ImageProcessingModel,
    success: function (data, status) {
        processEscapeKeyPress = true;
        var fn = window[successCallback];
        fn(data, passDataToCallback);
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        alert(err);
        processEscapeKeyPress = true;
        processAjaxError(xhr, desc, err);
    },
});
```

Comment: And if event that fails, try JSON.stringify on your data:
data: JSON.Stringify(ImageProcessingModule),

Comment: @stefchri- Tried both way but still problem remains same.